# CakePHP 4 - create migration of a manually created table

Tags: php, cakephp, migration

Using CakePHP 4.x

I have manually added a database table and want to create a Migration containing the table schema. I just want the structure without any of the data. This is so the table can be created locally for other developers, or for when the app gets deployed with the feature that uses the table.

The table is called `contracts_report` and is on the database defined in the `default` datasource key of `config/app_local.php`.

There is a section in the CakePHP docs about [Generating migrations from an existing database](https://book.cakephp.org/migrations/4/en/index.html#generating-migrations-from-an-existing-database).

It says (emphasis mine):

> You can also make sure the snapshot includes **only the tables** for which you have defined the **corresponding model classes** by using the `--require-table` flag:

> `bin/cake bake migration_snapshot Initial --require-table`

If I execute `bin/cake bake migration_snapshot ContractsReport --require-table` - where `ContractsReport` is the corresponding Model name for my table -  it generates a file which contains the structure of the entire database. In other words *all of the tables*, not just the one I've specified.

Using the table name as-is, `contracts_report`, instead of the Model name does the same thing.

All sections of the docs for existing databases use `bin/cake bake migration_snapshot` although I'm not convinced a "snapshot" is what's needed here.

The only other example of creating a table schema is doing it manually e.g.

> `bin/cake bake migration CreateProducts name:string description:text created modified`

That relies on specifying the column names and data types. Given they're already defined in the table I don't want to do that.

Can the table be read and the migration file generated accordingly or not?

Comment: Have you tried these steps: 1. before creating the table in the db, run bin/cake migrations dump , 2. create the db table manually , 3. run the command bin/cake bake migration_diff create_your_table name ?

Comment: Your first error is in thinking that `Initial` in the documented example is the name of a table. It's actually the name of the migration to bake. The bits you've highlighted there are not actually what you think they are. The word "defined" in there does not mean "listed on the command line", it means "written code for", i.e. it's going to generate a migration "only" for _all_ the tables referenced by classes in `src/Model/Table`. Your options are to generate the whole snapshot and then simply delete all the stuff you don't want, or follow @Salines advice.